# Outlook email conversion to json file format usiong pyspark

Tags: json, email, outlook, pyspark, email-attachments

I have around 1 lac outlook emails and want to convert them to json format using the distributed capability of pyspark. The outlook emails are first saved in .msg format and then the python algorithm to convert them to json format is executed. As the quantity of emails is very large, is there a way to make use of pyspark implementation to convert all the msg files to json using the distributing computing advantage of spark?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that indeed with pyspark but I cannot guarantee the performances.

```py
# first, acquire your data as a whole
rdd = sc.wholeTextFile("/path/to/files.msg")

# each line of your rdd will be a (key,value) pair where key is the path and value is the content of the file
# you need then to apply your python function to the "value"
json_rdd = rdd.map(lamba x : msg_to_json(x[1])

# json_rdd should now contain a json on each line, you just need to write it down
json_rdd.saveAsTextFile("/path/to/save/files.json")
```

On your side, you just need to prepare that `msg_to_json` function which take the content of a msg file as a string in entry and return a json file.

---

**EDIT**:
With your lib, it is going to be :

```py
import extract_msg
rdd = sc.binaryFiles("/path/to/files.msg")
rdd = rdd.map(extract_msg.Message)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Is it possible to load ".msg" files through wholeTextFiles() function call? If not, can you please suggest some other way? I have already implemented a msg_to_json() function in python, just looking for a way to integrate it with pyspark RDDs as mentioned by you.

Comment: hmmm, that is my answer ... is there something you do not understand ? just use the first line `rdd = sc.wholeTextFile("/path/to/files.msg")`

Comment: I tried running the command: `sc.wholeTextFile("/path/to/files.msg")` which is giving me output like this: `[(u'dbfs:/........./file1.msg', u'\ufffd\ufffd\x11\u0871\x1a\ufffd\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\')]` instead of the text content of body of the email.

Comment: apparently your file is a binary so try to use `sc.binaryFiles()` to read your data instead. It will give your the binary output of the file and then you can manipulate it.

Comment: I'm able to fetch the binary data but it is getting a bit difficult for me to convert it into text format. Do you have any ideas on how to perform the same?

Comment: how do you do that in python ? I dont understand. How do you open a .msg file in python and perform the transformation? No matter the way I show you how to open your file, it doesnt seem to fit what you expect. But it means that you probably expected something else than the .msg files ...

Comment: extract_msg is the library: `https://pypi.org/project/extract-msg/` that I'm using to open a .msg file in python but when I try to load the same .msg file into a RDD through sc.binaryFiles() [as the aim of this query is to process the .msg files through pyspark], it takes the content of the .msg file as binary value which I'm finding difficult to decode. Hence, needed help in decoding the same?

Comment: From the official doc : 
To use this in your own script, start by using:

`import extract_msg`
if you wish to send a **msg binary string** instead of a file to the ExtractMsg.Message Method:

```
msg_raw = b'\xd0\xcf\x11\xe0\xa1\xb1\x1a\xe1\x00 ... \x00x00x00'
msg = extract_msg.Message(msg_raw)
```

Comment: This is not helping either way. Even the edited answer is not giving me the desired result. Thanks for helping though. Let me know if have any other ideas to implement.